# Chromium: strange justified layout

Tags: chromium

With Chrome it looks good:

[image: chrome-fine--not-justifed]

But with Chromium it looks strange:

[image: chromium--strage-justified-layout]

Versions:

Google Chrome   99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Chromium    98.0.4758.102 (Offizieller Build) snap (64-Bit)

URL: https://thomas-guettler.de/tmp/peacefood.coffee-and-sugar.club.html

The same strange justified layout is in our on-prem Gitlab.

What could be the reason?

BTW, it happens on the [kind quickstart page](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#creating-a-cluster), too.

Comment: Very odd. I cannot duplicate this in any of my browsers unless I open the Developer Tools and begin modifying the `--bs-font-sans-serif` CSS variable to remove all fonts before `"Segoe UI Emoji"`. That said, editing this variable affects the entire page, not just the content of the table. Does your Chromium have some custom CSS files that it applies to sites to adjust `word-spacing` or `letter-spacing` values in specific CSS classes? This issue can also be intentionally duplicated in just the table by editing the `int`, `flex-grow-0`, and `flex-grow-1` CSS classes ... 

Comment: @matigo AFAIK I never fiddled with custom css. Where could I see custom css, if it is enabled?

Comment: Try as I might, I am unable to duplicate this issue. My Chromium snap is currently at version 99.0.4844.51, so I wonder if this is a version-specific bug 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After resetting my settings in Chromium, the layout works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Although the problem has been solved and, the OP has posted an answer, others may be interested in a full solution.

Tom's Guide has a very detailed answer:

- [How to reset Google Chrome](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/reset-google-chrome-how-to,news-18821.html)

Although, as the link's hover tool tip reveals, this is to get rid of "browser-hijacking adware", it worked for OP in this situation too.

A summary of steps (see the link for pictures):

1. Click the icon that looks like three vertical dots at the top right of the browser window.
2. Select "Settings" in the drop-down menu.
3. Click "Advanced" in the left-hand navigation bar in the resulting Settings page.
4. Select "Reset and clean up" at the bottom of the expanded menu.
5. Select "Restore settings to their original defaults."
6. Select "Reset settings" in the confirmation pop-up window.

See the article for more detailed instructions.